# SpriteKit: why does SKView disappear at one height but appears at another height? What's the maximum height for SKView?

Tags: ios, uiview, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

The code below shows a `SKView` until you change `skHeight` to 2050 or some higher value like 5000.

1) How can you make the `SKView` appear even at heights of 2050 or 5000?

2) What's the maximum size for `SKViews`?

**To reproduce:**

1) Run the code below. You will see the `SKView` represented as a gray window.

2) Change `skHeight` to 2050 or 5000. The `SKView` no longer appears.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create SKView
        let skHeight = CGFloat(2050)
        let skFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: skHeight)
        let skView = SKView(frame: skFrame)
        skView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Add test view to <scrollView>
        view.addSubview(skView)
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot replicated your issue. I've always a gray window changing `skHeight` also with 10.000. Tests maded with Xcode 9.4.1 and an iPhone SE. Could it related with a specific device?

Comment: 2048 is your limit because that is how large the frame buffer can be (actually it is 4096 but it is accounting for @2x retina).

Comment: why would you want your view to be that large anyway, no device has a screen larger than that

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks for the help! because the goal is to embed the SKView inside a UIScrollView. scrolling works great when the scene and SKView are < 2048, but it breaks when the SKView height is > 2048 because the SKView (and therefore the scene) no longer appears. also, some users like the first commenter report seeing the SKView with heights > 2048.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano could you try testing against the iPhone or iPad on the simulator? thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, the system is not really designed for what you want, but to get around it,  do not place your SKView in your UIScrollView,  place a filler UIView into it, then pass the scroll position into your SKView and move your scene.  If I had better context as to why you need a UIScrollView, I could maybe provide a better response

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks again! this question was borne out of the original question (scrolling the SKView). we tried using the filler UIView, but two levels of scrolling occurred: once with the UIScrollView and the second when moving the scene. how do you get around this?

Comment: You dont put the skview inside of your scroll view lol

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ugh, of course. :) so stupid! thanks! btw are you sure about the 2048 limitation? other users (like the first commenter) report seeing the SKView with heights > 2048. thanks again!

Comment: @Crashalot - first commenter said *"... always a gray window ..."* -- I don't think he ever saw the red subview.

Comment: @DonMag the SKView is not actually red, setting `backgroundColor` on the SKView does nothing actually (should have been removed from question). the SKView is represented by the gray window.

Comment: @Crashalot, it is not an issue with Metal Rendering, only OpenGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL rendering does not support canvas sizes greater than 4096x4096 on many devices, your view is 2050x2050, so when you factor in retina mode, it really becomes 4100x4100.

Now the @3x devices are even crazier, because it needs to handle the hardware scaling and shrinking, so you only end up getting views of about 1501x1501.

Metal does not have this problem, and as of iOS 12, OpenGL is deprecated, so hopefully the Simulators will be using Metal as well. (It should since Mojave only supports metal devices)

Comment: Metal has texture size restrictions depending on the GPU. Current maximum texture size in Metal is 16384×16384.