# Does SpriteKit SKView have a size limit?

Tags: skview

I had a problem，When I set up a larger width than screen for SKView, my skview just disappear.

If I setup SKView like this, it's visible:

```
SKView *skview = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
skview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:skview];
```

BUT if I give SKView a larger width, it's gone:

```
SKView *skview = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width*2, 100)];
skview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:skview];
```

Anyone knows why???

Comment: Found a same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108374/spritekit-why-does-skview-disappear-at-one-height-but-appears-at-another-height?rq=1